# Why i have a problem of scope in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

In my Handlebars code i have a variable undefined in the if block (or ifCond block) but without the if block i have a good result.

This is my code:

```
{{#each array}}
   <select>
      <option {{#if variable}}{{else}} selected="selected"{{/if}}>-    </option>
      {{#for x}}
         <option {{#ifCond ../variable this}} selected="selected"{{/ifCond}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}% {{../variable}}</option>
      {{/for}}
   </select>
{{/each}}
```

After the % in line 5, i have a good result.

Thanks for all help !

Comment: Try reversing the logic: `{{#unless variable}} selected="selected"{{/unless}}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an empty if, you can reverse the if by using `#unless`

```
{{#unless variable}} selected="selected"{{/unless}}
```

Comment: I found ! I'm very sorry, it's just that I put a triple equal and just the double equal, it's ok.
Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that because at this line:

```
<option {{#ifCond ../variable this}} selected="selected"{{/ifCond}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}% {{../variable}}</option>
```

It has the first "../variable" and he return "undefined" but the second "../variable" return "x" and it to return "x" in the first "../variable".

I will try "#unless" and I'll be back.

Sorry for my bad english, i'm french..

Comment: Can you remove this answer and add it as a comment instead, it's not really an answer at all - merci